# chai cannot compare class types

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, chai

I am using chai to compare if a returned value of type SimpleModel is of type SimpleModel. It gives me this error despite my IDE confirming that the types match:

```
AssertionError: expected {} to be a simplemodel
```

Here is my simple setup:

```
export class SimpleModel {
    public test_property: string;
}
```

and then i use it in my test like this:

```
it('(Simple Value)"', () => {
   const simpleModel: SimpleModel = new SimpleModel();

   expect(simpleModel).to.be.a('SimpleModel'); //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
});
```

Again simpleModel is, and my IDE confirms this, of type `SimpleModel`. I'm not sure why Chai also converts `('SimpleModel')` to `'simplemodel'` in the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` tests for `typeof` or `[Symbol.toStringTag]`. You must use `instanceof`.